# docker-compose - php - .htaccess - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, docker, apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I try to setup a **PHP** (vanilla) project with MVC architecture and docker-compose.

For my docker web service i use : **php:7.2.2-apache**

So it's look like:

[image]

This is my *docker-compose*:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"

  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
      context: .
    container_name: php_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    external_links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - "9191:80"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      PMA_HOST: db
```

and my *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Without *.htaccess* i can go to localhost and see my index.php, but with *.htaccess* i have a **500 Internal Server Error**

How can i properly configure my project ?
I try to follow this -> [MVC -  Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308361/how-to-mvc-in-php-without-the-use-of-some-framework) and [MVC - Github](https://github.com/kaurov/BlogNoFrameworkMVC)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule .* index.php
> ```

This rewrites *everything* (including any other static resources and `index.php` itself) to `index.php`. This will certainly break your app if you have any other static resources, although it shouldn't necessarily cause a rewrite loop (500 error).

Try the following instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The mod_rewrite directives don't actually do anything when you request the document root (the `DirectoryIndex` is served), but for any non-empty URL-path this applies.

However, this is still dependent on `.htaccess` overrides and mod_rewrite being enabled. (If mod_rewrite is not enabled then that could also be the cause of the 500 error - see the server's error log for details of the error.)

Comment: I have the same problem,  "RewriteEngine On"  give me a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: That sounds like mod_rewrite is not installed/enabled. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: How can check error log ?

Comment: @Anroche Download/view it in a text editor (or log viewer). The location of the file is determined by the `ErrorLog` directive in your server config. [Apache - Log Files - Error Log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#errorlog)

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite is installed and enabled https://stackoverflow.com/q/7337724/2010598